# Backend receiving date from database with -1 day i'm using react

Tags: javascript, html, sql, reactjs, database

At this point i have tried many solutions and i still have no idea why this is happening. For example on my database there is a date under the date_of_birth column that is 2023-12-29, when i look into my backend it shows as "date_of_birth":"2023-12-28T21:00:00.000Z" as you can see for some reason it is off by 1 day. I go to frontend and add a new student, check the database for the date that is stored in there , it is displayed correctly and then i go back into the backend it shows an offset by 1 day again.

i have tried changing the timezone of my database for some reason it shows that it has changed when i say show time in mysql it doesn't even budge and says SYSTEM.

i have tried implementing different ways to add date in my frontend nothing changed then i went back to my backend and tried implementing the date differently there didnt work.

i also tried making it so in my frontend it alters the received date with day+1 didn't work (i have no idea how it didn't work it just kept showing the same date)

again i tried adding +1 day into the backend it didn't work it still shows day-1 in the backend. here are my backend and frontend codes respectively.

Backend

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const mysql = require("mysql");

const app = express();
app.use(express.json())

 app.use(cors());

 const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host:"localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "Asd-DWEG3",
    database: "students"
 })

 app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    const sql = "SELECT * FROM student";
    db.query(sql,(err, data) => {
        if(err) return res.json(err);
        return res.json(data);
    })
 })

 app.get("/concessionscholarship", (req, res) => {
    const sql = "SELECT * FROM concessionscholarship";
    db.query(sql,(err, data) => {
        if(err) return res.json(err);
        return res.json(data);
    })
 })

 app.get("/fee", (req, res) => {
    const sql = "SELECT * FROM fee";
    db.query(sql,(err, data) => {
        if(err) return res.json(err);
        return res.json(data);
    })
 })

 app.get("/marks", (req, res) => {
    const sql = "SELECT * FROM marks";
    db.query(sql,(err, data) => {
        if(err) return res.json(err);
        return res.json(data);
    })
 })

 app.get("/stream", (req, res) => {
    const sql = "SELECT * FROM stream";
    db.query(sql,(err, data) => {
        if(err) return res.json(err);
        return res.json(data);
    })
 })

 app.post('/create', (req,res)=>{
    const sql = "INSERT INTO student(first_name,last_name,date_of_birth,department) VALUES (?)";
    const values = [
        req.body.first_name,
        req.body.last_name,
        req.body.date_of_birth,
        req.body.department
    ]
    db.query(sql,[values], (err,data)=> {
        if(err) return res.json("Error");
        return res.json(data);
    })
 })

app.listen(8081, () => {
    console.log("listening");
})
```

Frontend

```
import React, { useEffect , useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'


function Studetn() {
       const [student, setStudent] = useState([])
       useEffect(()=>{
           axios.get('http://localhost:8081/')
           .then(res => setStudent(res.data))
           .catch(err => console.log(err));
       }, [])


       // Function to format the date
  const formatDate = (dateString) => {
    const formattedDate = new Date(dateString).toLocaleDateString('en-GB', {
      year: 'numeric',
      month: 'short',
      day: '2-digit',
      timeZone: 'UTC'
    });
    return formattedDate;
  };


  return (
    <div className='d-flex v-100 bg-primary justify-content-center '>
        <div className='w-50 bg-white rounded p-3'>
            <Link to="/create" className='btn btn-success'>Add +</Link>
            <table className='table'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Student ID</th>   
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Surname</th>
                    <th>Department</th>
                    <th>Date of Birth</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {
                        student.map((data,i)=> (
                            <tr key={i}>
                                <td>{data.student_id}</td>
                                <td>{data.first_name}</td>
                                <td>{data.last_name}</td>
                                <td>{data.department}</td>
                                <td>{formatDate(data.date_of_birth)}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <button className='btn btn-primary'>Update</button>
                                    <button className='btn btn-danger ms-2'>Delete</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        ))
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Studetn
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want consistent date formatting, then you need to convert dates to strings on the server side instead of handling that on the client side.

Javascript is going to adjust date values for the current time zone.  This means  that if two users in different time zones use your application as-is, they're going to see different times.  You can get around this as described above.  Send preformatted strings to the browser, not date values.

Comment: ooh i also forgot to mention dates were working yesterday... is that why they are not working now?

Comment: oh.... it worked. it was that easy D: thank you.